# Swift/Navigation controller: back buttons returns "too back"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, back-button

The following is a screenshot of a fragment of my storyboard in the iOS application I am developing:

[image]

In this moment I am working in the last right bottom right table view controller (the one with the red arrow) which is a detail segue of the table view controller before (the one with the green arrow). The strange thing is that red table view controller the back button makes the application come back to the login screenshot while it is supposed to come back only to the green view controller. Why this? In the top of the screeshot there is another detail segue between those two table view controllers and the back button works perfectly as expected. Instead this does not happen on the botton. Is it because I added that navigation controller? I'm a bit confused...

Comment: When you are in Red View controllers have a break point when you push back button and look at self.navigationController.viewControllers . It will give you whether or not you are in the right queue.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion...I'm not an expert of this stuff. What do you mean exactly? And should I do if I were not in the "right queue"?

Comment: When you check for your viewControllers in self.navigationController it will give you an NSArray of viewcontrollers that you pushed your navigation controller to get your BVC. If there is only BVC in that array you have to trace down where did you pushed a new navigationController and make a fix in there. If it is not clear enough you can add me on skype sabrican.ozan